# Crontab not shows shell script containing cat command

Tags: linux, shell, cron

Here's my crontab code

```
* * * * sh /tmp/date_insert.sh
```

and /tmp/date_insert.sh

```
date >> /tmp/date.txt
/usr/bin/cat(or just cat) /tmp/date.txt
```

In every minute, date is added to date.txt well, but cat date.txt command shows nothing.

How to show the contents of date.txt on terminal screen every minute?

Comment: What do you mean by 'shows nothing'? Your cron job writes to stdout, which means that cron sends this output to you by mail. Did you set up mail correctly that it works with cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request you are making is odd.

> How to show the contents of `/tmp/date.txt` on terminal screen every minute?

How long would you want to see this file? One second, constant, a nanosecond ...?

Cron jobs are scripts that run on a periodic basis but are not designed to have live terminal interaction. If you want to have live terminal interaction, you have to perform other actions.

Output generated by cron-jobs, in this case the output of the command `/usr/bin/cat /tmp/date.txt`, will be send to your user accounts email. You can check it with the `mail` command. Nonetheless, if you want to inspect your file being updated, it is easier to just use the `tail -f` command. Just type

```
$ tail -f /tmp/date.txt
```

This will update every time `/tmp/date.txt` is updated.

Personally, I would change your cronjob into the following:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .----------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
  *  *  *  *  *   date >> /tmp/date.txt
  *  *  *  *  *   /path/to/script.sh >> /tmp/date.txt
```

with `script.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
date
```

Cronjobs are not difficult, but they can be puzzling sometimes. Fixing errors is generally very easy, but you need to know how to do it. For this I recommend to read the following page:

- [[SF] Why is my crontab not working and how can I troubleshoot it](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)